# terraform state show for items with count

Tags: terraform

When I have an instance that's been generated with `count` I am unable to see the state using:

`terraform state show instance-name.0`

If I use:

`terraform state show instance-name[0]`

that doesn't work either.

How do you show the state of an instance that has been built with `count`?

Comment: Can you show your full command and any error output?  You may need more than what you've put in your question - I would expect (in the case of AWS) to have something like `aws_instance.instance-name[0]` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed a character escaping issue. Square brackets really are reserved in bash, so adding single-quotes to the resource name did the trick. The command will become something like: `terraform state show 'azurerm_network_interface.web_server_nic[1]'`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is a quoting/escaping issue? Aren't square brackets a reserved character in bash? Poor answer maybe, but did you try it with single quotes around the resource address?

Answer (score 1):

For array:

```
terraform state show 'packet_device.worker[0]'
```

For for_each (it depends on your shell)

Linux, Mac OS, and UNIX:

```
terraform state show 'packet_device.worker["example"]'
```

PowerShell:

```
terraform state show 'packet_device.worker[\"example\"]'
```

Windows cmd.exe:

```
terraform state show packet_device.worker[\"example\"]
```

see
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/show

Answer (score 0):

it should work with the square brackets. If you do `terraform state list` you should see the resources you can show. Should be able to append this to `terraform state show`, e.g `terraform state show azurerm_network_interface.web_server_nic[1]`